# Application only works correctly on first run

Tags: android, eclipse, opengl-es-2.0, android-virtual-device

A few days ago, I began working on my first Android game. I opted to use OpenGL ES 2.0 since it was the most familiar alternative. However, I am currently unable to test the game on a real device, so I decided to use AVD instead, using a 4.0.3 virtual device with Intel HAXM installed. This seemed to work perfectly, but I have now encountered a really strange problem.

When compiling and running the game from Eclipse, it works just fine. However, if I then run the game a second time, either through the AVD or from Eclipse, nothing is drawn except the background color. If I change anything in the code so that Eclipse must recompile the application, everything once again works as it should, but only during the first run.

I have no idea what's going on. If I had to guess I would say that the AVD is acting up somehow, but does anyone know a way to fix this? If requested, I will provide relevant source code, but as I have no idea what could cause this kind of problem, I cannot provide any right now.

Comment: Does restarting the emulator fix it? Does clearing data (without reinstalling it)?

Comment: No, and recreating the AVD doesn't fix it either. However, I have found out that re-installing the application, like what Eclipse does upon recompiling, is what makes it work for that one single run.

Comment: That's odd. I'd say it sounds like some resource isn't being properly released, but since it still happens after you stop the emulator and start it again, that's probably not the case. I'd say the next step would be to clear data on the entire emulator, but that would uninstall your app, and reinstalling it seems to fix it... Could you post any clean-up code you have in your app?

Comment: This is a little embarrassing, but this is actually my first time using Java as well. I was under the impression that it took care of all garbage collecting by itself. However, I guess that I haven't implemented glDelete* calls yet, since Java doesn't have destructors and the structure of my program is still a little hazy. Could this be what is causing the problem? I find it a little strange how that would persist between runs though.

Comment: It could be, though like you, I find it strange it would persist across restarts. However, no way to know until you try. :) That being said, native libraries don't have GC in Java. Only pure native Java stuff does, or stuff that's designed to work with Java's garbage collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the textures were being deleted when the application was paused, which led to it not drawing anything on the screen. Reloading the textures in the `onResume` function fixed the issue.

Comment: you should select Peter's answer and give him some recognition points here on STO

Comment: @Martin I would like to do that, but that would require him to edit his answer and provide an actual solution to the problem. If people have the same problem they will have to read the comments to understand what must be done if I just accept his answer as it is now. However, if he does edit his answer I will not hesitate to accept and up vote it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any code that is saving or loading your application state that isn't working.  Perhaps through the onCreate/onStart/onPause functions?  Perhaps you are writing some state out when you suspend or close your application that is being read back in incorrectly??  Calling Application->Clear Data would reset this state unless you are writing to a public area such as the sd-card.

Comment: It seems we're on to something here. I mistakenly assumed that the application was stopped, but it was still running in the background. Doing a force stop and then restarting it restored the correct behavior. This probably means, as you say, that the problem lies in one of those functions. Give me a minute and I will check them.

Comment: Upon reading a bit, it seems like the OpenGL context is destroyed when the game is paused... Sigh, I guess I have to reload all the textures, VBO's, etc. again. I'll be back when I've tried it out. 
**EDIT**: It seems like only reloading the textures worked! Am I safe to assume that VBO's, shaders, etc. don't have to be reloaded?

Comment: I can't help you here as I haven't ventured into OpenGL in an Android app before.  That being said, I would have thought you'd have to reload everything.  Depends on whether your app was paused, stopped, or destroyed I guess...

Comment: onResume is exactly for that - reloading any data you need when your app went away and Android performed another activity, destroying data along the way.

Comment: @PeterCarpenter I guess I should reload the shaders and VBO's as well for now, just to be safe.

Comment: You effectively have 3 layers of your application being killed.  You have paused, stopped or completely destroyed.  If you're losing your state when the app is paused, then as @Martin said you can load your state in OnResume, if it's lost only when stopped, then you can do it in onStart, or if else if only when your app is completely removed from memory, then onCreate is the place to do it.  You'll definitely want to make sure that you have a clear idea of exactly what is happening here.